# Sails.js extend paginate to return custom object

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am trying to do paging on my api using Sails.js. Currently I use the paginate function when i search for something in my models but the thing is that paginate only returns an simple array of objects. What I want to is to take that array and wrap an object around it with this form:

```
{
  currentPage : x,
  totalPages  : y,
  result      : [the object returned from the model call],
  nextPage    : "url",
  previousPage: "url"
}
```

I could do it manually each time when the call returns a result but I was wondering if there is a way to intercept the result from globally and do it once for all my models?

Comment: I think it would be better to work on the blueprints than on the Model level. have a look at [blueprints documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) and if you need help with it just leave a comment here

Comment: that would defeat the purpose I think. currently I found that you can put methods on sails.config.models that are shared from every model you create and I implemented most of my functionality there. I removed the nextPage and previousPage from my initial object and will handle that in my controller

Comment: https://github.com/randallmeeker/SailsBluePrintActions/tree/master/pagination